# How to index a 2D array with 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, tensor

Today, i encountered such a problem:

Tensor `A` is a segmentation mask with the shape of `(1, 4, 4)` and its value is either 0 or 1.

Tensor `B` is a diagonal array created by `torch.eye(2)`.

My problems are why we can index `B`(2D) with `A`(3D) in the form of `B[A]` and why the result is a tensor with the shape of `(1, 4, 4, 2)`?

Above is my test instance, and the socure code is obtained from a diceloss class:

```
y_true_dummy = torch.eye(num_classes)[y_true.squeeze(1)]
```

the shape of `y_true` is `(b, h, w)`, `num_classes` equals `c`.

by the way, why we need function `.squeeze()`?

I want some explanation about the indexing problem and some videos are more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand the problem if you work on a smaller example:

```
A = torch.randint(2, (4,))
B = torch.eye(2)

>>> A
# tensor([1, 0, 1, 1])

>>> B[A].shape
# (4, 2)

>>> B[A]
# tensor([[0., 1.],
#         [1., 0.],
#         [0., 1.],
#         [0., 1.]])
```

`[1, 0]` and `[0, 1]` are the first and second rows of the 2x2 identity matrix, `B`. So, using the 1D array `A` of shape (4, ) as index is selecting 4 "rows" of `B` / selecting 4 elements of B along axis 0. `B[A]` is basically `[B[1], B[1], B[0], B[1]]`.

So when `A` is a 3D array of shape `(1, 4, 4)`, `B[A]` means **selecting (1, 4, 4) rows of B.** And because each row in B had 2 elements (2 columns), your output is (1, 4, 4, 2).

`B` is a 2x2 identity matrix, having 2 rows. Think of it like: you are picking 16 rows out of these 2 rows, getting a (16, 2) matrix -> then you reshape it to get (1, 4, 4, 2) tensor. In fact, you can check this easily:

```
A = torch.randint(2, (4, 4))
A_flat = A.reshape(-1)
B = torch.eye(2)

>>> torch.allclose(B[A], B[A_flat].reshape(1, 4, 4, -1)])
# True
```

This isn't also a PyTorch specific phenomenon either. You can observe the same indexing rules in NumPy, which torch maintains close compatibility with.